# Android.App.Activity is a type but a variable was expected

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
string[] arrays = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
ListView lstItems;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    // Get our button from the layout resource,
    // and attach an event to it

    lstItems = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
    lstItems.Adapter = new CustomAdapter(Activity, arrays);
}

public class CustomAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    //private  const int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    //private const int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

    string[] mData;
    //private TreeSet sectionHeader;

    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, string[] Data)
    {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext(context);

        mData = Data;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return mData.Length; }
    }


    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return mData[position];
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        //var data = mData [position];

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textViewHeader = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textviewHeaderItems);
            holder.textViewSeparator = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textviewItemsSeparator);

            convertView.Tag = holder;
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.Tag as ViewHolder;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= mData.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                holder.textViewHeader.Text = "Group A";
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                holder.textViewHeader.Text = "Group B";
            }

            holder.textViewSeparator.Text = mData[i];
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView textViewHeader { get; set; }
    public TextView textViewSeparator { get; set; }
}
```

In `CustomerAdapter`  I have a `string[] Data` parameter. After in OnCreate I got this problem at `lstItems.Adapter = new CustomAdapter(Activity, arrays)`. I don't understand.

I was trying to create a header listview on xamarin android.
I saw several samples but that code has much errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `Activity` class name. Instead you should pass an instance of the Activity you are in. You should be instantiating Adapter like below from Activity

```
lstItems.Adapter = new CustomAdapter (this, arrays);
```

Comment: I get a problem into GetView. Do you realize it? I have two layout file with textViewHeaderItems,extViewItemsSeparator

Comment: I want to initialize for both layout files

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` is a type. What you need is an instance of type `Context`. In Xamarin Android that's most commonly `Android.App.Application.Context`.

So your line should look like this:

```
lstItems.Adapter = new CustomAdapter(Android.App.Application.Context, arrays);
```

Comment: In application I have two layout files. How to convertView=mInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.file1,parent, false); for the both files.

Comment: @J.Joe That seems to be an entirely different question which you should ask separately.